# Not able to retrieve content control from word table in office 365 word online

Tags: javascript, office365, office-js, office-addins, word-contentcontrol

We have a product which supports on O365 windows and mac using office js. Now on the same product, we are going to support on O365 word online. 
During our work, we have found one discrepancy in O365 windows and word online. We have a document that has a word table inside a content control.

In word online, we can't retrieve content controls that are inside the word table, however, we can retrieving all content controls in O365 windows and mac desktop.

Following code snippet working properly in the O365 window and mac but not working in word online.

```
$("#run").click(() => tryCatch(run));

function run() {
  return Word.run(function (context) {
    var contentControls = context.document.contentControls
    context.load(contentControls, "id,text,title,tag,placeholderText");

   return context.sync().then(function () {
      /*console.log('The selected text was "' + contentControls.items.length + '".');*/
      contentControls.items.forEach((contentControl: Word.ContentControl) => {
        console.log('The Content control id "' + contentControl.id + '".');            
      });
    });
  });
}

/** Default helper for invoking an action and handling errors. */
function tryCatch(callback) {
  Promise.resolve()
    .then(callback)
    .catch(function (error) {
      // Note: In a production add-in, you'd want to notify the user through your add-in's UI.
      console.error(error);
    });
}
```

Comment: hi Hardik, I prepared a table with one cell and create one content control inside it. But I can correctly get it using your code. would you please share us your doc to repro it?

Comment: This was with the other than the rich text content control. Latest Office JS APIs support rich text content control only.

Answer (score 0):

Now with latest APIs, I am able to get the rich text content control from the table with same code.

Office JS API support only Rich Text content control type only.